# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'tmp/image.png' after downloading from GCS storage bucket before encoding to base64

Tags: node.js, image, base64, google-cloud-storage

I have an API endpoint that downloads from google cloud storage bucket and then converts the image to base64 before returning to response. It works most of the time, but after I deployed them on GKE, here and there I'm encountering the below error message.

```
return async function(req, res){
        let url = req.query.url;
        let urlArr = url.split('/');
        let bucket = urlArr[urlArr.length-2];
        let object = urlArr[urlArr.length-1];
        const imagePath = `tmp/${object}`;
        let response = "File not found";
        if(urlArr[0]!='https:' || urlArr[1]!='' || urlArr[2]!='storage.googleapis.com' || urlArr.length!=5) {
            res.status(500).json({
                err: "InvalidURLFormat"
            });
        } else {
            // Get the files
            const result = await storage.bucket(bucket).getFiles();
            const files = result[0].map(file => file.name);
            // Check if file exists
            if (files.includes(object)) {
                storage
                    .bucket(bucket)
                    .file(object)
                    .download({ destination: imagePath })
                    .then(() => {
                        const data = base64Img.base64Sync(imagePath);
                        fs.unlinkSync(imagePath);
                        res.send(data);
                    })
                    .catch(err => { console.log(err); });
            } else {
                      res.send("file not found");
            }
        }
    }
```

Error message:

> ERROR: { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'tmp/image.png'
>           at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
>           at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
>           at Object.exports.base64Sync (/usr/src/app/node_modules/base64-img/base64-img.js:60:17)
>           at storage.bucket.file.download.then (/usr/src/app/controllers/image.controller.js:958:40)

Comment: Share the code of importing image.png and the file structure as well. The information you shared will not help much. I suspect the issue is with incorrect path of the image

Comment: Hi @Think-Twice, I have updated the code and file structure, but it works maybe 95% of the time, so its strange to me why sometimes there are a few errors that pop up here and there.